# Solving cylindrically symmetric non-homogeneous wave equation $\nabla^2\mathbf{A}(s,t)-\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}\mathbf A(s,t)=\mathbf J(s,t)$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, electromagnetism

I'm trying to solve a non-homogeneous wave equation in cylindrical coordinates
\begin{align}
\nabla^2\mathrm A-\frac{\partial^2\mathrm A}{\partial t^2}=\mathrm J,
\end{align}
where A and J are cylindrically symmetric, i.e. they are functions of $s$ and $t$, (J is a separable function). The nabla operator can be written out explicitly,
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial^2\mathrm A}{\partial s^2}+\frac{1}{s}\frac{\partial\mathrm A}{\partial s}-\frac{\partial ^2\mathrm A}{\partial t^2}=\mathrm J.
\end{align}
If this were *spherically* symmetric, the $1/s$ would be a $2/s$ and I could solve this using the transformation $s$A$(s,t)$=B$(s,t)$ and d'Alembert's solution method, but I believe that doesn't work here. I also cannot find solution methods for non-homogeneous cylindrically symmetric wave equations online that don't involve separation of variables.

For a homework assignment I'm supposed to show that a certain solution satisfies this equation, (**not** to derive it, I would just like to), but it's complicated enough that I can't imagine someone guessed it, as well as not being separable. I could give more specifics on J and the solution, but I thought I'd keep it more general for the site.